How can you go from a rating of 1800 to 2000 in the Lichess?
For a very long time, my rating in Lichess has remained at 1800. How can my rating be altered? In order to overcome the 1800 rating barrier, how can I improve my chess training regimen?

Possibly related (not a dupe): Where can one find a complete chess curriculum?

Only you can answer this question.
When you are stuck on a plateau in chess (or in other subjects, really), it's always the same thing that needs to be done:

Figuring out WHY you lose the games that you lose

Figure out what kind of thinking error YOU make that causes you to make those mistakes

Figure out how you should be thinking in such situations instead

Find a way to train that new thinking and train it a lot.

Repeat.



At your level, your study priorities should be following:

Solve chess puzzle tactics. Try to visualize entire variants, don't just guess answers.
Play and analyze your games. It's better to play rapid tempo than blitz. After game, try to analyze without engine.
Study strategy books (for example Mastering Chess Strategy by Johan Hellsten).
Study endgames.

However, pushing from plateau will be hard, so be patient and reward will come.

I'm not gonna compete with the previous answer as it is by far the most solid one. So I'll take on a different angle on this question:
It possible to get to 2000 lichess fairly easily by making some tweaks to how you approach playing. I managed to reach 2000 with accuracy level of an 1800 lichess player
At the 1800 lichess (converts to about 1500-1700 on chess.com) It's very common for players to base their  opening reportoire on some streamer YouTube video. So there are a lot of players with little opening knowledge but play a handful of openings really well. This is what makes this rating level so demanding mentally, you win some games really confidently but loose also very quickly against some other players of same rating and its back and forth all the time.
But this in turn results in players often having poor knowledge in many classes of openings. I created a tool to quickly check players opening move weaknesses as well as some other stats. This can be done before matches or to scout your own chess.com account as well as recent opponents to know what openings you should be learning and how to make your opening portfolio better.
(important to note that it is cheating to look at such stats during a match )
You can check it out on
https://chesscomscout.com
I'm sure there are a bunch of other similar tools out there.
But his was the one that worked for me because with 2 kids I didn't have the time to browse all my games to reassess my repertoire.
Also you can look at the opening explorers in both lichess analysis and on chess.com at look at moves which have a good win rate. This can be effective when selecting openings to learn for your repertoire.
